# Unable to load validation xml file in struts2 framework

Tags: java, xml, struts2

I am trying to do validation on my action class Employee1. I used the file Employee1-validation.xml . I am getting an exception like this :

```
18:19:56,795 ERROR AnnotationActionValidatorManager:38 - Caught exception while loading file com/struts2examples/Employee1-validation.xml
Connection refused: connect - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:119)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.DefaultValidatorFileParser.parseActionValidatorConfigs(DefaultValidatorFileParser.java:82)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.loadFile(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:394)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildClassValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:279)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.buildValidatorConfigs(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:371)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.getValidators(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:99)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.AnnotationActionValidatorManager.validate(AnnotationActionValidatorManager.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doBeforeInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:222)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:203)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:290)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:995)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:849)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:632)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1270)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1237)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:260)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1153)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1049)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:962)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:117)
    ... 65 more
```

This is my empinfo1.jsp page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Form</title>
</head>

<body>
   <s:form action="empinfo1" method="post">
      <s:textfield name="name" label="Name" size="20" />
      <s:textfield name="age" label="Age" size="20" />
      <s:submit name="submit" label="Submit" align="center" />
   </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The struts.xml file I am using is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
   <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
   <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="1000000" />

   <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

      <interceptors>
         <interceptor name="myinterceptor"
            class="com.struts2examples.MyInterceptor" />
         <interceptor name="myinterceptor1"
            class="com.struts2examples.MyInterceptor1" />

      </interceptors>

      <action name="hello" 
            class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction" 
            method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="params"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="myinterceptor1"/>
            <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>

      </action>

      <action name="hello1" 
            class="com.struts2examples.HelloWorldAction1" 
            method="execute">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="timer"/>

            <result name="success" type="freemarker">
                <param name="location">/hello.fm</param>
            </result>
            <result name="nopassnofail" type="redirect">
                <param name="location">/NewWorld.jsp</param >
            </result>
            <result name="error">/AccessDenied.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="upload" class="com.struts2examples.UploadFile" method="execute">
       <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
       <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
           <param name="allowedTypes">image/jpeg,image/gif</param>
       </interceptor-ref>

       <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
       <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="loginaction" class="com.struts2examples.LoginAction"
         method="execute">
         <result name="success">/successLogin.jsp</result>
         <result name="error">/errorLogin.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="emailer" 
         class="com.struts2examples.Emailer"
         method="execute">
         <result name="success">/successMail.jsp</result>
         <result name="error">/errorMail.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="empinfo" 
         class="com.struts2examples.Employee"
         method="execute">
         <result name="input">/empinfo.jsp</result>
         <result name="success">/successEmpInfo.jsp</result>
      </action>

      <action name="empinfo1" 
         class="com.struts2examples.Employee1"
         method="execute">
         <result name="input">/empinfo1.jsp</result>
         <result name="success">/successEmpInfo.jsp</result>
      </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

The project workspace looks like :

[image: Project workspace]

The Employee1.java looks like :

```
package com.struts2examples;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class Employee1 extends ActionSupport{
   private String name;
   private int age;

   public String execute() 
   {
       return SUCCESS;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }
   public int getAge() {
       return age;
   }
   public void setAge(int age) {
       this.age = age;
   }
}
```

The Employee1-validation.xml file is in the same package.It is described below :

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">

<validators>
   <field name="name">
      <field-validator type="required">
         <message>
            The name is required.
         </message>
      </field-validator>
   </field>

   <field name="age">
     <field-validator type="int">
         <param name="min">29</param>
         <param name="max">64</param>
         <message>
            Age must be in between 28 and 65
         </message>
      </field-validator>
   </field>
</validators>
```

I am getting a warning on this line :

```
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

The file cannot be validated as the XML definition "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd" that is 
 specified as describing the syntax of the file cannot be located.

Comment: `Connection refused: connect` ???

Comment: running in localhost??

Comment: give permissions to java  to connect

Comment: Where is the file located? What is the schema for the file (e.g., show us the top of the validation file)?

Comment: @Dave : I added the details you mentioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I replaced

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
"-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN"
"http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
```

with :

```
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC "-//Apache Struts//XWork Validator 1.0.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/xwork-validator-1.0.3.dtd">
```

And now it's working fine. Thank you all who worked on this question.

Comment: cool. Yeah, if you use the wrong DTD, e.g., something not in the jar, it'll try to go find it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your files is in class path.Its a file loading problem.

Struts2 define a specific naming convention in defining validation xml files.

The format is  **ActionClassName-validation.xml**. So for your application file is Employee1-validation.xml, and struts name should be Employee1.

Note that this file should be present in the same package as of action class.